# Prove that there is a $\ M>0$ such that $\ |f(p)-f(p_0)|≤ M||p-p_0||$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem says:

Prove that if $\ f:R^2 → R$ is differentiable at $\ P_0$ then there is a$\ M>0$ such that $\ |f(p)-f(P_0)|≤ M||p-P_0||$ for a $\ p$ near to $\ P_0$

I beleive you have to use some Epsilon-Delta arguments, but I don't know how to do it...

I tried using that, since f is differentiable, the partial derivatives exist, but I don't know how to connect that with the Epsilon-Delta definition

Comment: What is the definition of a differentiable function that you are starting from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $p_0$ we have that there's a linear operator $D_{p_0}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{||f(p) - f(p_0) - D_{p_0}(p-p_0)||}{|p-p_0|} \to 0$ as $p \to p_0$.  In particular, if $|p - p_0|$ is small, then we have that

$$ ||f(p) - f(p_0) - D_{p_0}(p-p_0)|| \le |p - p_0|$$

By the reverse triangle inequality,

$$|| f(p) - f(p_0)|| \le  |p - p_0| + ||D_{p_0}(p-p_0)||$$

But $||D_{p_0}(p-p_0)|| \le ||D_{p_0}|| |p-p_0|$

Where $||D_{p_0}||$ is the operator norm.  So take $M = ||D_{p_0}|| + 1$.